# Is there a version of Golf Mk4 with ESP installation without on/off switch?

Tags: vw, golf, traction-control

Today I saw a Golf Mk4 from 2002 with 1.9 TDI engine and 110hp. The dealer says that the car has ESP system but there is no button to turn it off.

Is that possible? Why would the manufacturer install ESP system into the car and don't put a on/off switch?

Comment: Perhaps the manufacturers think the car can deal with extreme conditions better than most drivers... and, given some of the videos on the internet, they may well be correct... Or it could just be a cost saving...

Comment: That's a good point, but the strange thing is that most of the Golf Mk4 models with ESP have that on/off button

Comment: So was the centre console replaced and the switch not re-fitted... there can be many explanations...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. This is a Q&A site, so there is no need to preface your title with a **"Q:"**.  Enjoy the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mk4 platform, at least for UK models, cars with ESP include an override button on the console.  Either the switch has been replaced with a blank or more likely, the car doesn't have ESP.

Comment: You were right. I've checked the VIN and found that the car doesn't have ESP system.